# Android webview not loading images with site using cookie

Tags: java, android, webview, webkit

I am loading a SharePoint page into a webview using LoadUrl.  All the other content comes down but not the images.  The site requires a cookie to login but that part is working fine its just once you get past the login page the next page is correct minus the images.

String myUrl = "https://www.mysite.com/";

```
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setCookie(myUrl, cook);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();


    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
        {
            handler.proceed();
        }

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {

        }
    });
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);          webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(300);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webView.loadUrl(myUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have the same problem as I do.

Is it possible that the picture source require authentication? You can try to open the sources separately and see if you can access them or not.

I did the same and found out that the image sources I wanted to show are protected via a cookie and right now I'm looking for a solution to send this cookie along but couldn't find a way yet.

When I read you question that is exactly the same you try to do.

( sorry to write this here but I don't have enough points to write a comment )